# for-each not applicable to expression type required array or java.lang.iterable

Tags: java, for-loop, iterable

I try to consume json from web application into codeName1, so , i have to read json , to do this i have used the for-each loop , but i have an error in the compilation:

> for-each not applicable to expression type required array or java.lang.iterable

My code:

```
package service;

import com.codename1.io.CharArrayReader;
import com.codename1.io.JSONParser;
import com.codename1.ui.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import entity.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class UserService {
   public ArrayList<User> getAll(String json) {
       ArrayList<User> u = new ArrayList<>();

       try {
           JSONParser j = new JSONParser();

           Map<String, Object> p = j.parseJSON(new  CharArrayReader(json.toCharArray()));
           List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) p.get("root");
           for (Map<String, Object> obj : list) {
                //...
           }
       } catch (Exception ex) {
       }
       return u;
   }    
}
```

Comment: And unrelated: A) use meaningful names. u, j, p are all super meaningless names. They just confuse your readers. Never do that B) Also never ever go with **empty** catch blocks! Especially when going for a generic catch on `Exception`. At least print the exception. Ignoring errors is really the worst thing you can do after running into an error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
import com.codename1.ui.List;
```

You are using a **wrong** List type!

It should be

```
import java.util.List;
```

instead.

Or, the other way round: if you want to use that "custom" class `com.codename1.ui.List` with for-each, then that class **must** implement the [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove your import `com.codename1.ui.List;` and update it with `java.util.List`.
Look at your List `import com.codename1.ui.List;`. It's not java.util.List which implements Iterable.

```
public interface List<E>
extends Collection<E>
```

and Collection implements Iterable.

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>
```

Or, You can make your custom List to implement Iterable.
So your class should look like `com.codename1.ui.List implements Iterable {}`.

Comment: `Collection` *extends `Iterable`.